# Why 'variable can be only null at this location'?

Tags: java, null

I have this:

```
    String data[][] = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            data[i][j]= "test";
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Variable data is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first line should be

```
 String data[][] = new String[10][10];
```

Answer (score 4):

because you have to initialize your array first. Consider the array like a "pointer" in C/C++. You have to write something like `String data[][] = new String[10][10];`

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in java are kind of objects and have to be allocated with `new`.

Replace

```
 String data[][] = null;
```

with

```
 String data[][] = new String[10][10];
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course is data null, you explicitly said so. If you think that

```
String data[][] = null;
```

should initialize a 2-dimensional array and each value to null, you are mistaken.

What you need is for example:

```
String data[][] = new String[10][10]
```

*this* initialized a 2-dimensional array with 100 elements, that is to say: an array with 10 elements, each being an array with 10 elements.

An array in Java is an object, just like any other object, and thus has to be initialized with new. `data` in your example is a reference to an array which itself consists of references to other arrays (= objects).

Answer (score 1):

That is because you've assigned null to it. You need to create an array and assign that to data instead. Try this instead:

```
String data[][] = new String[10][10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Array assign value as a Reference type . to to asign any value in it, you have to first create instance of it otherwise it will give error. so you have to write the following :

```
 String data[][] = new String[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            data[i][j]= "test";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`String data[][]` is just a reference that can hold a two dimentional string array. since you have not added any object to the reference, it points to null

so do

```
String data[][] = new String[10][10];
```

to add an object in to the reference.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't initialize you array. you can define array size as per your need like given example

2d array it's like table row and column you must initialize first row size then column size

here are the example of initialization

```
data[][] = new String[5][]; // after this you need to define for 2d array like this
data[0] = new String[2];  
data[1] = new String[3];
data[2] = new String[1];
```

as above the column was dynamic you define the column size as much as you want 
another one is

```
data[][] = new String[5][3] then each row has 3 column
```